# Linux Ubuntu 20.04 - ownership changed to root for entire drive - permission changed to 777 for all files, cannot revert

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, chown, ownership

I am running Linux Ubuntu 20.04 and for some reason unknown to me, one of my storage drives suddenly has changed ownership to root and all file permisions are read/write/execute for all users. A peculiar thing is that I can still write to the drive and its folders without being root.

Running uname -a and lsblk gives the following output. The problematic drive is DATA1.

```
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt$ uname -a
Linux nano2 5.15.0-73-generic #80~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 14:58:14 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/766
loop1         7:1    0  73.9M  1 loop /snap/core22/750
loop2         7:2    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/140
loop4         7:4    0 460.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/105
loop5         7:5    0 349.7M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/137
loop6         7:6    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop7         7:7    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop8         7:8    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1891
loop9         7:9    0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop10        7:10   0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1950
loop11        7:11   0    46M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
loop12        7:12   0  12.3M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/959
loop13        7:13   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop14        7:14   0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19361
loop15        7:15   0 466.6M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/111
sda           8:0    0   7.3T  0 disk /mnt/DATA2
sdb           8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sdb1        8:17   0   3.7T  0 part /mnt/DATA1
nvme0n1     259:0    0   7.3T  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   7.3T  0 part /
```

In /mnt my data drives list:

```
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 May 10  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root  root  4096 Mar 20 12:18 ../
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  4096 Jul  4 11:30 DATA1/
drwx------  5 nano2 nano2 4096 Apr  3 10:35 DATA2/
```

Trying to run chown does not raise any error messages, but does not seem to do anyting either:

```
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt$ sudo chown -R nano2:nano2 DATA1/
[sudo] password for nano2:
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root  root  4096 May 10  2022 ./
drwxr-xr-x 20 root  root  4096 Mar 20 12:18 ../
drwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  4096 Jul  4 11:30 DATA1/
drwx------  5 nano2 nano2 4096 Apr  3 10:35 DATA2/
```

All files, existing and new get read, write and execute permissions for all users, and I cannot seem to change this with chmod:

```
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1$ mkdir test
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1$ cd test/
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1/test$ touch my_test.file
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1/test$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  160 Jul  4 15:11 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul  4 15:11 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  4 15:11 my_test.file*
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1/test$ sudo chmod 666 my_test.file
(base) nano2@nano2:/mnt/DATA1/test$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  160 Jul  4 15:11 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul  4 15:11 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jul  4 15:11 my_test.file*
```

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: `mount | grep DATA` please. In your question.

Comment: "A peculiar thing is that I can still write to the drive and its folders without being root." - this is to be expected as `777` grants RWX to owner, group, and all others.

Comment: What format are your data partitions. Windows formats like NTFS or FAT32 do not support Linux ownership & permissions. They are set for entire partition with the mount, either in fstab or when manually mounting. Post in question:  `lsblk -f`